# AWS glue data catalogue for metadata in AWS EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, amazon-emr

We are planning to use AWS EMR cluster for processing of json and parquet file. I have basic question that do we really need aws data catalogue for processing of json and parquet file stored in S3 bucket while submitting spark jobs in AWS EMR cluster? What is the advantage of using AWS glue data catalogue in case of using AWS EMR?

Answer (score 0):

In a Data warehouse or Data Lake, Glue Data Catalogue provides way to create & manage Metadata.

In data warehouses & data lakes it is the backbone of effective data management. It provides valuable insights into the data stored within the system and enhances data understanding, governance, integration, and accessibility.

Comment: Is there any significance of using it when we use it AWS EMR?

Comment: It doesn’t matter where you use , it will have above benefits.